# Can 25mL of 10% phosphoric acid substitute for 10mL of 25% solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Could I substitute $25~\mathrm{mL}$ of $10\%$ for $10~\mathrm{mL}$ of $25\%$ phosphoric acid solution?

This is for a measurement of free $\ce{SO2}$ in a sample of wine. The phosphoric acid is added to the wine sample and then more steps take it through a color change as it goes from acid to base. Finally a reagent is added dropwise to measure the amount of free $\ce{SO2}$ in the wine.

The full test is set out at More Wine.com as "Test for free SO2 in wine".

Comment: See my edits; if you disagree with any of them, feel free to change them back.  I was unable to find the webpage with the test; morewine.com is not even a live webpage. Can you post a link to the test webpage into your question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Not reliably.** Acid strengths measured in percentages are usually given as percent by weight, and if that's the case just swapping the volume numbers around will not provide you an accurate quantity of acid.

You first need to be sure of how the percentages are expressed.  Assuming they are percents by weight, you would then need to look up the density of phosphoric acid at the two percentages and work out the calculation so that you were adding the same number of moles of $\ce{H3PO4}$.